# Is it possible to use VBA to assign an Alias to a Query's fields for later use in a report?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database that runs compliance reports, In this there are 13 fields that need to pull X number of records during a query, based on if we're past compliance date, or before compliance date.

I've been unable to come up with successful code to properly filter the database, not for a lack of trying, people here were quite adept and had good suggestions on previous answers, but alas none of them provided the desired results.

What I would like to do is have the end user click a button on the form, and have that button assign an alias to a column in a saved query, then have the report pull that.

For scope of things, I could have coded a python app to do this in no time, but I don't know enough VBA to get it done, don't need hand holding, but resources, or starting and key points would be helpful.

Comment: Use VBA and DAO to modify query object. However, how would changing an alias in query object resolve issue of filtering data?

Comment: The aliases are part of the query's definition, so you're looking at programmatically modifying a query definition by tweaking specific tokens in it... sounds like an X-Y problem, because modifying a query's definition will very likely break anything that's already using that query, and I wouldn't write a SQL parser in VBA to do this. Consider connecting with ADODB and querying the view/table, and then *that query* can use whatever aliases its client needs to use, and it can even be constructed at run-time from sanitized user inputs if you're feeling adventurous.